# Two block system with strings

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics

[image]

Cant figure it out, can anyone tell me how to do it plus the general methodology for solving 2 or 3 block system questions.

Equations: (ū is coefficient of friction)

P-f1-f2=M2a

f1-Tcos45=Ma

f1=(M2g-Tcos45)ū

f2=(M1g+M2g-Tcos45)ū

4 equations but 5 variables?

I took friction between M2 and ground as f2 and M1 and M2 as f1.

Comment: Hi and welcome to physics.SE! Please note that [homework-like questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714/50583) and [check-my-work questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093/50583) are generally considered off-topic here. We intend our questions to be potentially useful to a broader set of users than just the one asking, and prefer *conceptual* questions over those just asking for a specific computation.

Answer (score 2):

Because the blocks "just slide", what you have here is a situation where the forces are (almost) in balance. Forget about the acceleration; get rid of acceleration (you are not trying to solve for that) and make one of the expressions an inequality.  This should allow you to solve the problem.

Comment: Just slide as in they just start moving with different accelerations. So they are still moving with a common acceleration. My understanding is that first the two block will slip on the floor and move with some acceleration then as we increase the force the bottom block moves with a greater acceleration than the top block and hence they slide. So we need to find the maximum force of common acceleration. Am I wrong?

Comment: The top block isn't accelerating as it is held by the string. The acceleration of the bottom block can be as small as you want... essentially "anything greater than zero". Which is why an inequality can be used and $a$ can be eliminated.